# Cassandra group results by date / period

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I want to make a query that will give me the results grouped by hour(or date ,or year,...etc). In this example I have 4 records 2 for 7 am , and two for 8 pm.

So I want to make the query so it will give me the results grouped by hour. 
So the result would be something like

```
1 - 7:00 , 56
2 - 7:00 , 76
3 - 8:00 , 6
4 - 8:00 , 7
```

Is this possible?

```
INSERT INTO table
    (key, timestamp, value)
VALUES 
    ('1', '2016-04-25 07:00:03', 56);

    INSERT INTO table
    (key, timestamp, value)
VALUES 
    ('2', '2016-04-25 07:00:05', 76);

    INSERT INTO table
    (key, timestamp, value)
VALUES 
    ('3', '2016-04-25 08:00:03', 6);

    INSERT INTO table
    (key, timestamp, value)
VALUES 
    ('4', '2016-04-25 078:00:05', 7);
```

Comment: Your example of a result is kinda confusing, do you want it key=1, timestamp=7:00, value=56? Do you want to see all the keys at 7:00, or the last entry for each key?

Comment: Hi, I want to do something like this,  select * from table
 group by key, timestamp ( hour / day / year)

Comment: if its `PRIMARY KEY (key, timestamp)` or `PRIMARY KEY ((key, timestamp))`  you can. get the timestamp for a given hour/day/year and use that to query